Print PDF file with highlighted texts using viewer.js
I am using viewer.js and trying to print pdf file with highlighted text in it.
I have tried to print pdf file by selecting background graphic, but it did not work. I have also used
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; in @media print but it also did not work.


Note: I might be doing in wrong way. Suggesting me to solve in the right directions would be appreciable.

What do you mean by "…highlighted text…"? "…by selecting background graphic…"?

i have set a color for some text like here 'and' and what i want is to print pdf with that highlighted text in pdf file.

That highlight doesn't affect the bytes of the PDF file. ViewerJS is simply a PDF viewer not a PDF editor. You need a different approach. I'll write an answer when I get out of the office.

I have modified the setHash() in viewer.js and setting background color different for different text. In my requirement I need to download pdf file with highlighted text. Can you guide me how can I achieve this dynamically.

The text you see in a PDF.js viewer is NOT the "true" PDF text for saving as a modified PDF it is simply like OCR layers an invisible HTML screen overlay of an image display of the true page contents. It is "Emulation" of how a true PDF reader may function with vector text. This is the primary reason it is lightweight enough to work in mobile devices, where binary based Browser Plug-in PDF viewers cannot.
Let me show you, by slightly offsetting the text and colour it red. Thus the selected text is NOT the text internal to a PDF for saving. When the PDF is saved it will discard all that temporary screen text, which is only used for text search or assisted "Read Aloud".

Highlights are "areas" inside a PDF, thus are actually very similar. They too are an "overlay" and not truly anchored or in any way related to underlaid text. So can also be shifted just as easily, but editors resist doing that with "text highlights".
So in order to append user selected highlights a separate PDF application needs to talk to the middleman the PDF.js "worker.js" where annotations can be appended to the source.pdf. SEE the red squiggly highlight I added with PDF.js is retained and can be recoloured/resized in any other editor and is seen as overlaid in MS Edge.
There are many such applications depending on platform etc and perhaps the most commercial of those is PDF.js Express but there are many others, and you could write your own method to send user data to the worker.
In a binary Web PDF plugin even secured from JS exploitation the highlights will be directly attributed to the PDF rendered text and can be saved as appendages to the file. So this is how True
PDF viewers like Edge/Chromium's can save the "Annotation" colours.


